# How to put a menu over the full width of the page using HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, css, menu, nav

I just have debuted with the web language (HTML, CSS) and I am creating my First page. I find a template html horizontal menu that I would like applying to my page. Unfortunately I don't arrive to modify it for he applies to all the width of my page.

I explore the net to try to find how to do and I think it should be linked with the property `width = 100%`.

I think the solution should be easy, but even watching the StackOverflow post on similar problems I have not found. When i apply the solutions found in my code it doesn't work.

Here is the code:

```css
body
{
 background-color: black; /* Le fond de la page sera noir */
}

#nav
{
padding:0;
}

#nav li
{
display:inline;
}

#nav li a
{
font-family:Arial;
font-size:12px;
text-decoration: none;
float:left;
padding:10px;
background-color: #333333;
color:#ffffff;
border-bottom:1px;
border-bottom-color:#000000;
border-bottom-style:solid;
}

#nav li a:hover
{
background-color:#9B1C26;
padding-bottom:12px;
border-bottom:2px;
border-bottom-color:#000000;
border-bottom-style:solid;
margin:-1px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="menuStyle.css" />
    <title>Antoine</title>
</head>
<body>
   
 <ul id="nav" style="clear:both;">
   <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Sitemap</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
 </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it displaying your `ul` (`#nav` ID) as `inline-block` and then setting `width: 100%.` Also, you should add a `background-color` to see the effect.

```css
body
{
 background-color: black; /* Le fond de la page sera noir */
}

#nav
{
padding:0;
display: inline-block;
width: 100%;
background-color: #333333;
}

#nav li
{
display:inline;
}

#nav li a
{
font-family:Arial;
font-size:12px;
text-decoration: none;
float:left;
padding:10px;
background-color: #333333;
color:#ffffff;
border-bottom:1px;
border-bottom-color:#000000;
border-bottom-style:solid;
}

#nav li a:hover
{
background-color:#9B1C26;
padding-bottom:12px;
border-bottom:2px;
border-bottom-color:#000000;
border-bottom-style:solid;
margin:-1px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="menuStyle.css" />
    <title>Antoine</title>
</head>
<body>
   
 <ul id="nav" style="clear:both;">
   <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Sitemap</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
 </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It works perfectly thank you too for the speed and quality of your response.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should add this, if you like your menu to be 100% width of your page.

```
#nav
{
padding:0;
width: 100%;
float:left;
background-color: #333333;
}
```

*background-color: #333333* - Added just to make it more visible.

Comment: It works perfectly thank you for the speed and quality of your response.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to learn and use bootstrap, because it makes this easy. In your case it is very simple, you will create 2 `<div>` elements outside of your `navbar`. One to make the width `100%` and apply your background and then another to centerlize your code.

My answer to your question:

```
<style>
.full_width{
    width: 100%;
}
.centerlize{
    width:1024px;
    margin: 20px auto;
}
</style>
<body>
    <div class="full_width">
        <div class="centerlize">
            <ul id="nav" style="clear:both;">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sitemap</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Don't advice people that learn to code HTML & CSS to use Bootstrap - it will just limit the learning they do. Using it for production is up to you, using it to learn HTML & CSS is **not**.

Answer (score 0):

```css
 body {
   background-color: white;
   /* Le fond de la page sera noir */
 }
 #nav {
   /* reset unordered list to not use default list styles */
   list-style: none;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   /* add display flex with space around and vertical centering...also stop wrap */
   display: flex;
   justify-content: space-around;
   align-items: center;
   flex-wrap: no-wrap;
   /* color needed on background also to look consistent */
   background-color: #333333;
 }
 #nav li a {
   font-family: Arial;
   font-size: 12px;
   text-decoration: none;
   float: left;
   padding: 10px;
   color: #ffffff;
   border-bottom: 2px;
   border-bottom-color: transparent;
   border-bottom-style: solid;
 }
 #nav li a:hover {
   /* avoid changing size or position of things on hover...this can cause content to jump */
   background-color: #9B1C26;
   border-bottom-color: #000000;
 }
```

```html
<ul id="nav" style="clear:both;">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">About</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Services</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Products</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Sitemap</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Help</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This is just an example of what you can do, certainly not the gold standard but will get you thinking about the possibilities.  Hope this helps.  The CSS was commented with changes.

Comment: Thank you , you have helped me on what I wanted to do next.

Answer (score 0):

Try tp put the menu list into a DIV like this:

```css
body
{
 background-color: black; /* Le fond de la page sera noir */
}
#navdiv
{
 padding 0;
 background-color: #333333;
 width: 100vw;
 height: 34px;
}
#navul
{
padding:0;
width: 100vW;
}

#navul li
{
display:inline;
}

#navul li a
{
font-family:Arial;
font-size:12px;
text-decoration: none;
float:left;
padding:10px;
background-color: #333333;
color:#ffffff;
border-bottom:1px;
border-bottom-color:#000000;
border-bottom-style:solid;
}

#navul li a:hover
{
background-color:#9B1C26;
padding-bottom:12px;
border-bottom:2px;
border-bottom-color:#000000;
border-bottom-style:solid;
margin:-1px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="menuStyle.css" />
    <title>Antoine</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="navdiv">
 <ul id="navul" style="clear:both;">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sitemap</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```